# How to get the number of failed authentication attempts from OKTA

Tags: single-sign-on, okta, okta-api

We are using Okta services for SSO, and we are trying to find an API endpoint to retrieve a count for failed login attempts.  We wish to provide user feedback in order to inform them when they are close to hitting our set number of failed login attempts limit.

We noticed in password policy we can specify a maximum number of attempts in the `Lock out user after` section.

I expect a password authentication failed response object to include a property such as `failedAttempts:4`... is there such a property?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API that can give you the count of failed login count exactly. However, you can use events API from Okta to almost achieve this http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/events.html.

What you can do is use events API to get failed login attempts after certain time. You can use API call such as

/api/v1/events?filter=published gt "2013-07-01T00:xx:yy.zzzZ" and action.objectType eq "core.user_auth.login_failed"

to get failed login after certain time window. You can be more precise by using certain time (A few seconds before last login attempt) by changing xx:yy.zzz to your values and get failed login attempts after that time.

Once you have all failed login attempts after the given time, you would need to parse the JSON to see how many failed login attempts have been made by specific user.